# QT OpenGL QGLWidget cannot be found

Tags: qt

I am new to Qt and I have problem. I downloaded *Qt SDK for Open Source C++ development* from http://qt.nokia.com/downloads/sdk-windows-cpp, I add C:\QT\2010.05\bin in my PATH. When I start some demo projects it works, but when I create same project (I create a new project and copy the source code from the demo) it shows an error like "QGLWidget cannot be found" (I need to create an OpenGL project). Do I need to add anything else to my PATH? Does anybody know what could be the problem?

Answer (score 10):

Edit your .pro file and add `opengl` as an option to `QT`:

```
QT += core gui opengl
```

Answer (score 8):

You need to add the OpenGL module in your project file (.pro) as explain in the doc: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtopengl-index.html#details

Answer (score 4):

**For Qt 6+**, add `QT += openglwidgets` instead of `opengl`, as per [the documentation.](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qopenglwidget.html)

Comment: Added this and still have the error in qt6 unfortunately

Answer (score 3):

From Qt 6, you need to use cmake to access this. This is how you would do it:

```
find_package(Qt6 REQUIRED COMPONENTS OpenGL) 
target_link_libraries(mytarget Qt::OpenGL)
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
find_package(Qt6 REQUIRED COMPONENTS OpenGLWidgets) 
target_link_libraries(mytarget private Qt::OpenGLWidgets)
```